# There is natural surjective map from $U(\mathbb{Z}_n)$ to $U(\mathbb{Z}_m)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $m,n$ be positive integers where $m$ divides $n$. Then there is a natural map $$ \phi : U(\mathbb{Z}_n) \to U(\mathbb{Z}_m)$$ $$ [a]_n \mapsto [a]_m$$
> for any integer $a$ with $\gcd(a,n) = 1$. Show that this map is surjective.

I do find the statements intuitive, I considered proving it along the lines of showing that $U(\mathbb{Z}_m)$ is either equal to or contained in $U(\mathbb{Z}_n)$.  Because $m=nq$ for some integer $q$, all numbers relative prime to $m$ is relatively prime to $n$. If my intuition is correct this map would necessarily be surjective?